# как сделать так чтоб и .env файл не выгружался и значение с переменной было доступно в коде на сервере?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, .env

Есть локальный .env файл с переменной REACT_APP_API_KEY='условный ключ' в gitignore етот файл не попадает и соответсвенно на github тоже, как сделать так чтоб и .env файл не выгружался и значение с переменной было доступно в коде на сервере, build приосходит на netlify с файлов которые автоматически подтягиваются из github

Comment: https://www.netlify.com/blog/a-guide-to-storing-api-keys-securely-with-environment-variables/ - там нет ответа?

Comment: да оно самое, спасибо!)